# expl3 -- sort a token list

Tags: expl3, sorting, token-lists

> L A TEX3 comes with a facility to sort list variables (sequences, token lists, or comma-lists) according to some user-defined comparison.

I try to adapt the `interface3` manuel example to a token list, but it fails.

! Missing number, treated as zero.

Maybe the argument `BCA` is counted as one token, that's a second is missing for sorting procedure, but then how to trasform `BCA` in `ABC` ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_foo_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\Sort}{m}{%

\tl_set:Nn \l_foo_tl { #1 }
\tl_sort:Nn \l_foo_tl
{
    \int_compare:nNnTF { ##1 } > { ##2 }
    { \sort_return_swapped: }
    { \sort_return_same: }
}   

\l_foo_tl

}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Sort{BCA}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're not comparing numbers

Comment: Are you having uppercase and lowercase letters? The predefined function to convert letters to numbers in expl3 is `\int_from_alph:n { a }`.

Comment: No haven't lowercase letters in a name of a triangle and there will be it's no a problem they come after uppercase, the poit to name the triangle allways with the same ABC not BCA, but I call the macro with BCA because it is rectangle in B. Thank you for the convert to number function, what is your idea with this suggestion ?

Comment: @Tarass egreg finally added that to the answer below. I didn't want to add an answer just to add that idea.

Comment: @Manuel Yhank you I understand your point now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to compare *numbers*. If your input only consists of characters, you can use

```
`<char>
```

Here's a working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_tarass_sort_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\Sort}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tarass_sort_tl { #1 }
  \tl_sort:Nn \l_tarass_sort_tl
   {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { `##1 } > { `##2 }
    { \sort_return_swapped: }
    { \sort_return_same: }
   }

  \tl_use:N \l_tarass_sort_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Sort{BCA}

\end{document}
```

If you want to consider equal upper and lower case versions of the same letters, use `\int_from_alph:n` that returns 1 from `A` or `a`, 2 from `B` or `b`, and so on, so

```
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \int_from_alph:n { ##1 } } > { \int_from_alph:n { ##2 } }
```

would sort `bCA` into `AbC`, whereas the code above would produce `ACb`.

Comment: Thank you. I looked for other prefix_compare, but didn't find anything for caracters. Where is ` documented and is there some other usefull trick as this one to know, and where to find them ;-) Thank you again.

Comment: @Tarass Backquote-character is standard TeX syntax for an alphabetical constant, denoting the character’s ASCII code. There are no interfaces for string comparison, at the moment.

Comment: I made a function to reuse the sorting process on characters, it works but I prefer someone check and improve it (there is several type type of functions and other possible mistakes). Do I post it here as an edit or as a new question ?

Comment: @Tarass There is [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: The tex tag says : `TeX is a typesetting system, where the output is defined by command-sequences. Note that http://tex.stackexchange.com is specifically dedicated to TeX questions. ` and is not very active : 29 questions in 4 years.

Comment: @egreg May be mention a more general `\alph_to_int:n` or something like that?

Comment: @Manuel Whenever TeX is looking for a number, backquote-character will work.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I know, but it's something more from primitive TeX, I meant in case you wanted to comment a more “general approach” for this kind of things with LaTeX3 commands.

Comment: @Manuel There is no expl3 “general approach” to this.

Comment: @egreg perhaps worth adding an `\int_from_char:N` or similar?  There is `\int_from_alph:n` IIRC that works in base 26, treating upper/lowercase ASCII letters as "digits".